# Switft 5 generate exception on async call

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Hi since I made the conversion to swift 5 of my app I have a whole series of errors on asynchronous calls, one of the many concerns the code written below, how can I fix this? the code makes a rest call to a node.js backend. The code makes a rest call to a node.js backend to execute some queries on a db, until before the swift 5 implementation I had no problem whatsoever, how can I solve this

**Expection**: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'

**View:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        var MessageError = "Errore"


        if(self.u.PermessoAccessoPosizione() == true) {
            self.u.Marcatura(Longitudine: Float(self.Longitudine)!, Latitudine: Float(self.Latitudine)!, Stato: Stato.description, completion: { result in

                    if(result != "true")
                    {
                        MessageError = "Errore: " + result
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: MessageError, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else {

                        var Message = ""
                        switch Stato {
                        case .Ingresso: Message = "Ingresso registrato"
                        case .Uscita: Message = "Uscita registrata"
                        case .Arrivo: Message = "Arrivo in cantiere"
                        case .Partenza: Message = "Partenza dal cantiere"

                        }

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "MarcaTempo Aggiornato", message: "" + Message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
        }
        else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Abilita Acessso a posizione", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    });
self.ChangeButtonColor(color: UIColor.white)
```

**Controller:**

```
func Marcatura(Longitudine: Float, Latitudine: Float, Stato: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            let rtemp = UserModel()
            var IdUtenteMarcatura: Int = Int(self.GetIdUtente())
            if(self.IdUtente > 0) {
                IdUtenteMarcatura = self.IdUtente
            }

            rtemp.Marcatura(IdUtente: IdUtenteMarcatura, Longitudine: Longitudine, Latitudine: Latitudine, Stato: Stato, completion: { result in
                completion(result)
            })

            self.IdUtente = 0

        }

    }
```

**Model:**

```
func Marcatura(IdUtente: Int, Longitudine: Float, Latitudine: Float, Stato: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ())
    {
        let jsonrequest = JSON()
        let jsonarray: [String: Any] = ["IdUtente": IdUtente, "Longitudine": Longitudine, "Latitudine": Latitudine, "Stato": Stato]
        jsonrequest.GetSingleString(Router: "/Utente/Marcatura", ValueArray: jsonarray, completion: { result in
            completion(result)
        })
    }
```

Comment: What exception do you get and in which line? The exception trace would be nice.

Comment: I have add exception in the hurry I had forgotten to add it @Roberto

Comment: Message is explicit. UI related stuff can be made only in main thread. Use a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`. Also, name your var starting with a lower case.

Comment: I have remove DispatchQueue, 
but the error continues to exist

Comment: Then you're still running on a background thread. Likely `Marcatura()` is being called from the background. You must ensure that you're on the main thread for all UI work. It is possibly coming from another part of your code. The exception should include the line that's causing the problem.

Comment: Dirty way: Englobe your ` completion(result)` with `DispatchQueue.main.async {  completion(result) }`